# PS/LaTeX figure exported with Xfig doesn't render properly

Tags: graphics, external-files, eps, xfig

I just installed the basic version of MiKTeX 2.9 on my Windows XP system. I compile this very simple document (`test.tex`) with TeXworks, using the default pdfLaTeX command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \input{segment.pstex_t}
  \caption{Segment $s$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Where the input is a simple figure with a segment (a polyline) with a label $s$. After compiling, I get the label in the figure, but not the polyline.

Comment: It seems like you're exporting the file from Xfig using the [Language](http://www.math.wpi.edu/Doc/xfig/xfig.3.2.3d/Doc/html/printing.html#language) "Combined PostScript/LaTeX". This exports a `.pstex_t`, a `.pstex` as well as a `.eps`. Try compiling this with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: It is not exporting the `.eps` (don't know why). Should I do it manually?

Comment: Update: even when exporting the `.eps` manually, it doesn't work. Do you want me to copy the code from the `.pstex` and `.pstex_t` files?

Comment: First try compiling with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` and see if this works. The `.pstex` file is most likely the same as `.eps`.

Comment: I've converted my comment(s) into an answer, since this seemed to solve your problem. If you still have problems correctly setting TeXworks to automate the `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` compiler sequence, you could consider posting a [follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When choosing the export [Language](http://www.math.wpi.edu/Doc/xfig/xfig.3.2.3d/Doc/html/printing.html#language) "Combined PostScript/LaTeX", [Xfig](http://www.xfig.org/) exports a `.pstex_t` (containing overlay text information) and a `.pstex` (similar to EPS format) file.

Compile your document using a `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` sequence to produce the correct output.

---

In general, you could also remove the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package option `dvips`, since the correct driver should be detected automatically.